# How to solve complex system of equations using matlab?

Tags: matlab, wifi

I have to analyze 802.11 saturation throughput using matlab, and here is my problem. I'm trying to solve parametric equations below (parameters are m,W,a) using solve function and i get

> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found

[image]

[image]

How could I solve above equations using matlab?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were trying to find an analytical solution for `tau` and `p` using symbolic math. Unless you're really lucky with your parameters (e.g. m=1), there won't be an analytical solution.

If you're interested in numerical values for `tau` and `p`, I suggest you manually substitue `p` in the first equation, and then solve an equation of the form `tau-bigFraction=0` using, e.g. `fzero`.

Here's how you'd use `fzero` to solve a simple equation `kx=exp(-x)`, with `k` being a parameter.

```
k = 5; %# set a value for k
x = fzero(@(x)k*x-exp(-x),0); %# initial guess: x=0
```